# Qt,CodeBlocks minGW problem with dependencies

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, codeblocks

Hi there i got a problem with my project.I want to remove all dependencies so all the project will require are Qt dll's.
I'v added -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ to linker but still its not linking libgcc.
When i try to run program without libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll in its directory i got an error that this dll is missing.
Anyone that could help with removing that dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Qt and want to build statically your application, first of all, you should statically build Qt SDK before.

For more information see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/deployment-x11.html